# How to replace Android's default share dialog?

Tags: android

I'm looking into building a simple app that replaces Android's default share dialog* (much like [Andmade Share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andmadesoft.share) and [Appchooser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.noxi.apppickerpro)).

The first step would be (giving the user the option to) replacing the default share dialog. Andmade Share and Appchooser have shown it's possible - even though those apps are pretty old, it still works on current versions of Android, so there must be some kind of Broadcast Receiver intent I can use to hook into it, and that should give the user the option to set a default app for handling Share intents.

So the question is: how?

(*) Just in case you are wondering "why??": I hate the Direct Sharing feature. It's slow and I never use it. Since Google refuses to make it optional, I decided to replace the whole thing. "How hard can it be?" :)

Comment: Are you saying the ShareActionProvider is slow? Have you tried this? https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction

Comment: I'm not looking into creating a share intent, i'm looking how I can hook into Android's system so I can *handle* share intents from other apps. Please take a look at the app's I provided as an example. They replace the share dialog for every app that (that doesn't implement its own share dialog - which is bad practice, right Google Youtube, Photos and Messaging?)

Comment: I've mailed the developer of AppChooser and it turns out his code is open-sourced on github. I need to check it out, but the answer probably is buried in his AndroidManifest: https://gist.github.com/noxi515/3142bb117fc4afa8c186cbc9589e8879

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I've mailed with the developer of AppChooser and he was so kind to provide the answer.

The secret sauce I needed can be found inside the `<action>` and `<category>` tags:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

So, to summarize:

```
<activity
    android:name=".app.ChooserActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```